# How to resize window and make it bigger than screen size?

Tags: macos, calendar

My OS screen resolution shown in Settings>Displays is 1600px in height

My Calendar app window is 1600px tall (full screen mode). I want to make that 3200px (or 3000px).

When I try to manually resize the window such that it should be bigger than 1600px in height, OS automatically shrinks it.

How can I do that?

Comment: I do believe, IMHO, that in macOS you can't have a window bigger than the screen size. I have seen it *accidentally* from time to time but never on purpose. Once you manage to get most of the (inadvertently too big) window back on screen it will resize, at least in my experience.

Comment: How are you manually resizing it? My hunch is when your cursor hits screen edges, the system adjusts to make content visible. Also, I wonder if third party window manager moom would have that feature for you - https://manytricks.com/moom/